# Vite library with Windicss

Tags: vite

I am using Vite (Vue3) with Windi CSS to develop a library. I am using library mode for the build (https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode) with the following config:

**vite.config.js**

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), WindiCSS()],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/lib.js'),
      name: 'MyLIB',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
      // into your library
      external: ['vue'],
      output: {
        // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
        // for externalized deps
        globals: {
          vue: 'Vue',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

My entry file (`src/lib.js`) only includes a few Vue components in it and looks like this:

**lib.js**

```js
export { default as AButton } from './components/AButton/AButton.vue';
export { default as ACheckbox } from './components/ACheckbox/ACheckbox.vue';
import 'virtual:windi.css';
import './assets/fonts.css';
```

When I build the library I get the js for just those components but the css is for every Vue file in the `src` folder and not only the ones i included in my `lib.js` file. I know the default behavior for Windi CSS is to scan the whole `src` folder but in this case, I only want it to scan the components I added to my entry.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to restrict the scan by using `extract.include` and `extract.exclude` options, see there :  https://windicss.org/guide/extractions.html#scanning

#### From the doc

> If you want to enable/disable scanning for other file-types or locations, you can configure it using include and exclude options